# Play/pause buttons launches iTunes instead of playing/pausing the Deezer app

Tags: macos, itunes, keyboard, mojave, music

I am using the Deezer app music. It worked well, I could use the media buttons to control play/pause/next track/previous track. But a few days ago, (after an macOS update?) now when I hit play/pause it launches iTunes instead of controlling the Deezer app that is already running and playing music. It was correctly functioning before, so I don't know where this change of behaviour is coming from. This is very annoying as it makes the Deezer almost unusable as I have to bring it to front to control it.

Comment: Question re-opened, please post the solution you've found as an answer below.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Found the answer on the Deezer community forum:

You have to allow Deezer the accessibility rights, go to:

- System Preferences
- Security and Privacy
- Privacy tab
- Choose "Accessibility"
- Add "Deezer" to the allowed software

You'll have to unlock the configuration by clicking on the lock and enter your system password.

The original answer can be found [here](https://en.deezercommunity.com/other-devices-49/media-control-keys-not-working-on-desktop-beta-app-with-mojave-18169).

Comment: Did it on Catalina, still launches iTunes :(

Comment: @artem I may be a little bit late to the party but  just tried this on Catalina and worked like a charm.

Comment: @artem Even after rebooting?

Comment: it launches Apple Music for me too, but if Deezer is running, it will take the media key presses